# What is the standard notation for the set of rationals with finite fractional part?

Tags: notation, rational-numbers, fractional-part

As the title says. What is the standard notation for the set of rationals with finite fractional part, when written in base $n$ with a radix point? I expected $ℚ_n$, but that's taken for n-adic numbers.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by "fractional part".  Do you mean a finite decimal expansion?  All rational numbers, written as decimals, in any base (where "decimal" may not be really appropriate!) has either a finite number of digits after the decimal point or is a repeating decimal.  I don't believe there is specific notation for such rationals.  I will observe that in base 10 such decimals are those that, in fraction form, reduced to lowest terms, have only factors of 2 and 5 in the denominator.  And for general n, have only the prime factors of n as factors in the denominator.

Comment: @user247327 Yes, I mean a finite base-$n$ expansion. I **need** a standard notation for it for my next seminar.

Comment: I've never seen a standard notation for that. You can make up a notation and take 30 seconds to explain it at the start of your seminar. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: They were going to need to take those 30 seconds to explain the notation anyway, whether or not they had made.it up. So it may not be ideal, but it is optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of all rationals with eventually-terminating base-$k$ representation has a snappy algebraic description: it's the smallest [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) containing every integer as well as ${1\over k}$. The standard notation for this is $$\mathbb{Z}[k^{-1}]$$ (or $\mathbb{Z}[{1\over k}]$), which in my experience is usually pronounced "$\mathbb{Z}$ adjoin $1\over k$" or "$\mathbb{Z}$ adjoin $k^{-1}$."

---

The square brackets, incidentally, are important: when working with fields, round brackets refer to the smallest *field* extension containing the given element. So e.g. ${1\over\pi}\not\in\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$ but ${1\over\pi}\in \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. That's not an issue here, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Brackets vs. parentheses seem to be an issue here. One can't write parentheses to a ring that is not a field. Though due to the COVID-19, the seminar was cancelled. Mama mia.